# React native app crashes in start after Native-Base font setup in android

Tags: react-native, native-base

After setting up font theme with native base using this guide https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#theme-font-headref my app crashes after opening it in android without throwing any error.

It works fine in IOS.

Any similar experience?